# How can I update all rows in a table before creating a new one?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create table on **Postgres with Sequelize** that will have an `active` column. This column will be set to `true` when a new row is created, but I need to set all the other rows to `false` (or only the ones with true) before the new row is created.
I've been looking in the hooks section, but I don't know how can I update from inside the model's own hook...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like :

```
User.beforeCreate(user => {
   return User.update({ 'active' : false }).then(user);
});
```

Please note the name `User` is a model , and `user` is instance.